# How many proxies created in Java application use Spring core, Hibernate, Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, proxy

I'm reading about Java proxy and as we know Spring Core, Hibernate, Spring AOP, Ehcache is an implement of it. I have got confused cause SpringCore will create a proxy, Hibernate will create a proxy and SpringAOP or Ehcache will do the same if we use all of them in a Java project.

***How many proxies will create?*** Can someone help me out this problem and give me some example?

Answer (score 1):

Each of those frameworks create any variable number of proxies all based upon certain design choices and configurations.  That said, the only way to have any idea would be to profile your application.

Most frameworks that use proxies leverage them for similar reasons.  These proxies are meant to act as placeholders that look like an object our code knows about and works with; however the internal implementation details are hidden, often supplemented with framework specific business logic.

For example, hibernate may expose a lazily-loaded collection of objects as a collection of proxies.  Each proxy looks like the object our application expects in that collection; however, the internal state of that proxy is often not yet loaded until first accessed.  In this case, the proxy saves on memory consumption, result-set parsing and database bandwidth, and  a plethora of other things.